# Object Reference Not Set

Tags: c#, .net

There are similar questions around here but none that fit into my my particular case scenario.

I have a Windows Form with a Button. The button is attached to the event handler as follows:

```
private void mybutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do some processing here
}
```

In addition there is a combobox where a change in selection in supposed to trigger the button event handler as defined above.

```
private void mycombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mybutton_Click(sender, e); // this is the line which pops up the dialog
}
```

The code works exactly as intended at runtime but i get a dialog prompt at compile time which reads:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

There are no other errors or warning.

A google search tells me that this message is an error caused if the program is trying to access a member of a reference type variable which is set to null.

However when i run this code in debug mode, both the sender and event(e) variables are not null.

So why is this dialog popping up ?

And if this had been an error or warning - it should have shown as an error or warning but nothing of that sort happens.

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

**Edits: Answering Questions Raised in Comments**

There are no errors as you can see in the screenshot.

The program works great - just this pop up

The popup is caused by the line:`mybutton_Click(sender, e);` in the combobox `selectedIndexChanged` function.

The `mybutton_Click(sender, e)` does not use any of the arguments sender or e in the processing.

I have not installed any VS extensions either.

Comment: What code do you have in place of 'do some processing here'?

Comment: what is location of hat error ? If it runs on RELEASE but produces problems *at compilation* in DEBUG, this could be related some Forms designer problem, usually restring VS resolves problem.

Comment: you say it happens at compile time? That makes no sense. post your stack trace!

Comment: Post more code and post the line where the error occures

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of error message you reading?

Comment: As @Tigran said there is a big chance that the code is failing in the designer. your constructor isn't called in this case and if this event handler is called in design mode and depends on things set in the constructor it will fail. You can test if you are in design mode and just do nothing in this case.

Comment: Please don't seed your question title with tags, it isn't necessary.

Comment: Have you installed any VS extensions? If so, then try to disable them and restart VS.

Comment: show the implementation of `btnEncode_Click`

Comment: You can actually debug designer issues by firing up another VS instance and attaching the debugger to the other one, then attempt to use the designer in the other one after having put some breakpoints in your code. Useful if you are authoring your own controls.

Comment: @Dennis: Strange as it sounds - Restarting VS solved the issue :(

Comment: Could you post the whole class?

Comment: Just as an FYI, to call the click event as if the button was actually clicked, call mybutton.PerformClick() and forget about senders and event args;

Comment: You could put the logic from mybutton_Click in another method since you don't need sender and EventArgs. Then call this method in mybutton_Click and mycombobox_SelectedIndexChanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what is happening is that the events are firing in Design mode (which I seem to recall happening to me a few times when using WinForms back in the day).

To get around it what I did was handled the form load event, then in that I attached a listener to the SelectedIndexChanged. Then in Design mode the event isnt bound and wont fire, but at run time it is bound.

Something like:

```
public void form_OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += mycombobox_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not a good design to call the `Click-event` of the button in the `SelectedIndexChanged-event` of the ComboBox and this might also be the reason for the error.

Better put your logic in a seperate method and call it in the Click- and the SelectedIndexChanged-event like this:

```
private void UpdateSomething()
{
    // Do whatever you want
}

private void mybutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateSomething();
}

private void mycombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateSomething();
}
```